# signalR JavaScript client can't receive messages after reconnecting using an iPad

Tags: signalr

signalR JavaScript client appears to reconnect after the iPad sleeps but does not appear to receive messages.

We have the following Nuget packages / version of signalR installed on the server. We also using the same version of the signalR JS client in the Web client:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

These are the steps to reproduce:

1) We start the signalR connection in the Web client on user login.

2) iPad receives notifications.

3) Leave the Web client idle and let the iPad sleep.

4) Try to use the Web client after 5 mins approx. According to our application server logs and the signalR server trace logs signalR reconnects but the Web client does not receive any messages.

We used the instructions found here to enable signalR server tracing:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing

Below is the entire Transport log:

fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905 is the intial connection.

a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e is new connection.

Let me know if you need any more information.

```
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection 3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176 is New.
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection 5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162 is New.
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : 3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : 3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : 3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : 3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : 3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : 3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : 3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : 3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Removing connection 3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : Abort(3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : End(3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Verbose: 0 : Cancel(3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (3ebca988-ef0b-49a1-b9f1-7934ea64f176)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905 is New.
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : Abort(5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Removing connection 5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : End(5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (5b1d35aa-0d65-45f1-b681-1d7b04569162)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905 is dead
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Removing connection fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : Abort(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : End(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Verbose: 0 : Cancel(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (fa47e685-528b-46fc-ae56-4dc647065905)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e is New.
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(a102e5ec-7bfd-449a-93d5-671cfd2bb19e)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the client goes to sleep and disconnects you will not be able to continue to connect to that client using the same connectionID, they will have a new connectionID and you will have to associate the new connectionID with that user.